# im having an illegalStateException : EntityFactory was not set! with fxgl

Tags: java, javafx

this is my code:
Main:

```
import com.almasb.fxgl.app.GameApplication;
import com.almasb.fxgl.core.math.FXGLMath;
import com.almasb.fxgl.settings.GameSettings;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends GameApplication
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initSettings(GameSettings gameSettings)
    {
        gameSettings.setTitle("Shooter");
        gameSettings.setVersion("1.0");
        gameSettings.setHeight(1000);
        gameSettings.setWidth(1600);
        gameSettings.setCloseConfirmation(false);
        gameSettings.setProfilingEnabled(false);
        gameSettings.setIntroEnabled(false);
        gameSettings.setMenuEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initGame()
    {
        getMasterTimer().runAtInterval(() -> {

                getGameWorld().spawn("Enemy",
                        FXGLMath.random(0, (int) getWidth() - 40),
                        FXGLMath.random(0, (int) getHeight() / 2 - 40)
                );

        }, Duration.seconds(1));
    }
}
```

the problem is with getgamewolrd().spawn("Enemy") it says
.IllegalStateException : EntityFactory was not set! 
this is my Factory class:

```
import com.almasb.fxgl.annotation.SetEntityFactory;
import com.almasb.fxgl.annotation.Spawns;
import com.almasb.fxgl.ecs.Entity;
import com.almasb.fxgl.entity.Entities;
import com.almasb.fxgl.entity.EntityFactory;
import com.almasb.fxgl.entity.SpawnData;
import com.almasb.fxgl.entity.component.CollidableComponent;
import com.almasb.fxgl.entity.control.ProjectileControl;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

@SetEntityFactory
public class Factory implements EntityFactory
{
    @Spawns("Bullet")
    public Entity newBullet(SpawnData data) {
        return Entities.builder()
                .from(data)
                .type(EntityTypes.BULLET)
                .viewFromNodeWithBBox(new Rectangle(10, 2, Color.BLUE))
                .with(new CollidableComponent(true))
                .with(new ProjectileControl(new Point2D(0, -1), 300))
                .build();
    }

    @Spawns("Enemy")
    public Entity newEnemy(SpawnData data) {
        return Entities.builder()
                .from(data)
                .type(EntityTypes.ENEMY)
                .viewFromNodeWithBBox(new Rectangle(40, 40, Color.RED))
                .with(new CollidableComponent(true))
                .build();
    }

}
```

does anyone see anything wrong please help thanks!

Comment: this seems very specific to the `com.almasb.fxgl` library, which I have never heard of before - try to see if you can support from the developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you do not have a package. The annotation processor is disabled when the main class does not have a package. Just put both classes into the same package for the processor to pick up your factory class.

Alternatively, you can set the factory manually by `getGameWorld().setEntityFactory(...)`. The former approach is preferred in case there are other annotations in use.

Comment: Thank you Almas !

Comment: I put them all in one package and is still is giving me the same error could i have imported the lib wrong?

Comment: I fixed it I had to make an instance of the Factory class manually like you said lol thanks!

Comment: It has come to my attention that package names with uppercase letters in them are not properly scanned, which may have been the case.